# Plane to produce beveled edges on plywood?

Tags: plywood, hand-planing, bevels

I have this small project of bevelling the edge on a 3 1/2" x 2 1/2"  piece of 1/2" plywood. I'm replacing and duplicating a damaged platform on which an audio speaker foot rests. I will be bevelling 2 sides which are cross grained.

Notwithstanding using a router which I don't have, I'd appreciate input and advice from experienced woodworkers on the plane they'd use for this. (I'm trying to find out if there would be a specific type of plane/bed angle that would be more effective on 1/2" ply.)

Comment: Do you already own a sharp plane?

Comment: These pieces are pretty small, do you have access to a table saw?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Asking for the "best XXXX (anything)" is not a good way to ask things since it invites responses that are opinion-based, which isn't [a good fit for the SE model](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). As you specifically mention not having a router can we presume you do have a plane or planes? If so which ones? Any of them (literally any) could be used for this, given suitable methods.

Comment: @Ashlar — I hope you’re thinking about a robust work-holding jig for the tablesaw… pushing a tiny piece like that through all by itself is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yeah... meant to comment on that. If I had a cross-cut sled with a beveled edge and hold down clamps, I'd be willing to bevel an edge on the 2.5x3.5" piece, but I wouldn't do that any other way. That's a great way to lose fingertips or more...

Comment: No, I just own several rasps... and on test trial while rough, it wasn't that bad of bevel.  But I'm trying to find out if there would be a specific type of plane/angle blad that would be more effective wit 1/2" ply.  If I knew how to work a router and was accustomed to it.. I would simply nail the piece to a larger board and clamp that down and work the router around the smaller piece.

Comment: *"If I knew how to work a router and was accustomed to it.. I would simply nail the piece to a larger board and clamp that down and work the router around the smaller piece."* That's some good thinking to fix the part in place, but actually when the workpiece gets down to a certain size the rule of thumb is generally you bring the work to the router rather than the router to the workpiece. In short, you'd use a router table (or a very very simple equivalent — nothing but a piece of ply/MDF/particleboard with a hole bored in it for the bit to protrude.

Answer (score 5):

Since plywood will inherently give you a cross grain planing situation (no matter which edge of your rectangles you're working with) which can be difficult, and you give no indication whatsoever of the quality of the plywood you're working with, I'd suggest an alternative:

Sand it.

With heavy grit sand paper, you'll probably make quick progress even if doing it by hand. Then as you approach your bevel angle, you can switch to finer paper to sneak up on the final bevel, then finish with a very fine grade for a nice finish.

Comment: A stationary belt or disc sander is very handy for such things, if available.

Comment: Yes, that was one of my thoughts... to have a moving but stationary sanding belt upon which to to form the bevel

Comment: Power tools would absolutely make this easier, however, the OP gave the impression that hand-tools were preferred and that power tools might not be available. However the answer of "Sand it" doesn't imply hand or power. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I'd appreciate input and advice from experienced woodworkers on the plane they'd use for this.

I wouldn't have a preference, as long as the iron in the plane were good and sharp.

I frequently do have need to plane the edges of plywood and I pretty much split the task equally between a block plane and a no. 4, depending on mood.

**Note:** it's only because the workpiece is quite small that it argues against using anything longer. In general you can use any plane up to an 8 to plane a plywood edge but I think anything longer than a 4 (approximately) would just be too unwieldy here. *If the workpiece is held and you're running the plane over it.*

There are alternatives though, one that's sometimes used when the workpiece is small, and that is to *hold the plane in a vice and push the workpiece over it*. Yes there is potential for running the fingers into the cutting edge doing it this way so care must be exercised.

> (I'm trying to find out if there would be a specific type of plane/bed angle that would be more effective on 1/2" ply.)

Honestly, no.

Because of the presence of end grain on each alternate ply in plywood, a common answer to this in modern woodworking would be to use a block plane<sup>1</sup>, because of the perceived wisdom about planing any end grain.

Quite apart from standard bench planes being quite capable of planing end grain<sup>2</sup> (even if not ideal for the task) it is worth remembering that all the other plies are oriented the other way, i.e. they present long-grain surfaces on the same edge.

So even if one did have a firm preference for a bevel-up plane for end grain and a double-iron plane otherwise, you have to decide on your acceptable compromise.

---

<sup>1</sup> And by extension in recent years a bevel-up smoother or bevel-up jack plane, because they have the same basic geometry and blade arrangement (single blade, held with the bevel on top).

<sup>2</sup> Set fine, and with the blade extremely sharp.

Comment: I wanted to thank all of you for your feedback.  Project accomplished.  I'm neither a woodworker by profession or hobby but have a great appreciation for those who are knowledgeable and skilled at it... especially living in New England where one can see workmanship that are works of art.  Especially want to thank Freeman and Graphus who enabled me to approach and complete my project with success.

Comment: You're very welcome, that's what we're here for. Appreciate you taking the time to say thanks, you'd be amazed at how seldom that happens.